# How to use focus() event in mozilla firefox?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have used `focus()` method, but it does not work on Mozilla Firefox. I have used the following code in asp .net:

```
protected void drgBranches_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtLoginName.Text = drgBranches.SelectedValue;
  txtLoginName.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine on my end. Can you make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This link says these events doesn't support mozilla http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onfocusin_eventdelegation

Comment: Just use the regular [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) and [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) events. You will probably have to use to set the `useCapture` argument in `addEventListener` to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just the regular focus

```
<input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1">

$("#target").focus(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3o11wnus/